# InnerHTML of my custom polymer tag overrides everything in <template>

Tags: polymer

I just don't know how to tell my custom element where to render the inner html of my custom tag, i.e:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <span>Hello from <b>my-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM.</span>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<my-element>Hi!</my-element>
```

Renders:

> Hi!

I want to be able to tell my component where and how to use whatever I put between my custom element's tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bring in elements from the outside (light dom) and render them inside your shadow dom, you need to define insertion points using a `<content>` tag:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <span>Hello from <b>my-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM.</span>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/najiquzivofu/1/edit

You can also select specific children using the `select` attr:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element2" noscript>
  <template>
    <span>Hello from <b>my-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM.</span>
    <content select="p"></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<my-element2>
  <div>This won't render</div>
  <p>This will because the insertion point invites it in the shadow dom</p>
</my-element2>
```

See http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html#shadow-dom-subtrees and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-301/#toc-distributed-nodes for more.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<content></content>` inside your `<template>`.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" noscript>
  <template>
    <span>Hello from <b>my-element</b>. This is my Shadow DOM.</span>
    <content></content> Polymer,
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<my-element>Hi!</my-element>
```

#### Renders

Hello from **my-element**. This is my Shadow DOM.

Hi! Polymer,

For reference: [Shadow DOM](http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html)